# Regex with different pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following strings

```
s1 = 'XXX-2 I LOVE : XXX XXX'
s2 = 'FOOD : XXX'
s3 = 'XXX-FOOD : XXX
```

I would like the following

```
s1 = '2 I LOVE'
s2 = 'FOOD'
s3 = 'FOOD'
```

`s2` only has 1 delimiter `:` while `s1 & s3` have 2 `- & :`

I would like to keep everything between the two delimiters `- & :` so I use the following `\-(.*?)\:` however I don't get `s2`

If I use the following `\w+\-?(.*?)\:` I get everything before `-`

I am terrible at regex, if someone could help me with this one and provide a link to understanding regex I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `s2` doesn't have two delimiters to use?

Comment: exactly why I am stuck

Comment: s2 doesn't meet your description of the original regex, so it's not clear what you want your regex to save. Additional explanations and/or examples are necessary.

Comment: perhaps the changes help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need is: `(?:\w+-)?(.*?):`

`(?:\w+-)?` says to check for an initial sequence of word-like characters `\w` followed by a hyphen. Since we have that in parantheses, the question mark after it says this entire part is optional - i.e., either there will be `\w+` and `-` at the beginning of the line, or neither of them will be there. The `?:` part is just to tell Python that you're using the parantheses `()` here just for grouping, not because you want the matching parts to be captured and stored.

`(.*?)` - This matches the parts we actually want, and stores that in the capture group number 1. So if you have `m = re.match(r"(?:\w+-)?(.*?):", 'XXX-2 I LOVE : XXX XXX')`, then `m.group(1)` will contain `2 I LOVE`.

(Note that neither `-` nor `:` need a backslash escape in regex in general (`-` needs quoting just inside `[]` character classes), so you can just write them out without escaping them.)

You might find tools like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3rdob) useful for exploring and understanding regexes.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should work for your example

```
(?:[^-]+-)?([^:]+):.*
```

Comment: how dude just how??? Thank you so much. Is this just from experience or do you mind sharing a good resource.

Comment: You're most welcome, regex looks scary at the beginning, but it gets easy when you get used to it. I just wrote that, but a good tool to test your regex is https://regex101.com/

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!!! It looks so confusing at first but I want to get much better at it.

Comment: Just a note, @Sundar answer has more explanation on regex, and using `\w+` instead of `[^-]+` will work for your example, but will not work if you have a non-alphabet character befor the `-`

Comment: yes I was playing around with the link you provided me and ran into that problem.

Answer (score 1):

We are using `strip` to remove the trailing space.

```
s1 = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+|X','',s1).strip()
s2 = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+|X','',s2).strip()
s3 = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+|X','',s3).strip()

2 I LOVE
FOOD
FOOD
```

Comment: I was going to resort to this since I was losing hope thank you!